# How to use gulp-include plugin

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a project where I use gulp as a building tool. What I would like is to since I have 2 same pages with different content, include header, footer and navbar html file in them. 
My folder main index.html is in the root folder project, and there I have also folder partials with header, footer and navbar. How can I set up gulp include so that I can use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  /*=include partials/header.html */

  <body>

    /*=include partials/navbar.html */

    <div class="container form-container">
      <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

From [gulp-include documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include) add this to your html

```
<!--=include partials/header.html -->
```

like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <!--=include partials/header.html -->

<body>

    <!--=include partials/navbar.html -->

    <div class="container form-container">
      <div class="row">
```

I assume your header.html and navbar.html have only those elements, i.e., no body tags and then your gulp file is simple:

```
var gulp  = require("gulp"),
include   = require("gulp-include");

gulp.task("include html", function() {
  console.log("-- gulp is including html partials");

  gulp.src("index.html")
    .pipe(include()).on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```